# can't display photos in bootstrap slider from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have an `api` , and i create page to display all photos from the `api` using `bootstrap` slider and fetch data every 20 seconds ..
i use the exact code from `bootstrap` website but when run my code only the first image  is appears.

i can't set all code here because is large . but i set it in photos.
this is part of my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
     $( "#transactions" ).remove();
     const url = 'http://airport-system.tk/api/get_available_transaction';
     let jsondata;  
     fetch(url).then(
    function(u){ return u.json();}
  ).then(function(json){
    //start transaction div
    var para_transactions = document.createElement("div");
    para_transactions.setAttribute("id","transactions");
    var element = document.getElementById("body");
    element.appendChild(para_transactions);
    //end transaction div
    //start col-md-9 div
    var para_col_md = document.createElement("div");
    para_col_md.setAttribute("class","col-md-9");
    para_col_md.setAttribute("id","test_col");
    var element_transaction = document.getElementById("transactions");
    element_transaction.appendChild(para_col_md);
    document.getElementById("test_col").style.marginTop = '50px';
</script>
```

and this is my all code :

[firstphoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9zXv.png)
[second photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSGQG.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll need to create a minimal example/snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: i edit my question and put all code